# What is the meaning of brackets in this code

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am self learning Xamarin forms. While learning I came accros this code and I do not understand part of the code - `(TripLogEntry)e`.
a) Why is there TripLogEntry in brackets?
b) how is this called/named in literature and
c) what does it do/what is purpose of this brackets?

```
async void Trips_SelectionChanged(object s, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var trip = (TripLogEntry)e.CurrentSelection.FirstOrDefault();
        if (trip != null)
        {
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new DetailPage(trip));
        }
        // Clear selection 
        trips.SelectedItem = null;
    }
```

Comment: That's [Casting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions#explicit-conversions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are parentheses: `()`, not brackets: `[]` or braces: `{}`, and this is called Casting. Here's some good documentation: [Casting and Type Conversions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions).

In this case, it means that `e.CurrentSelection.FirstOrDefault()` will be explicitly converted to an instance of `TripLogEntry` (instead of just [`object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.selectionchangedeventargs.currentselection?view=xamarin-forms)).

Answer (score 2):

those are parentheses "()" - brackets are square "[]"

that is the C# [casting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions#explicit-conversions) operator - it casts a variable of one type to another type

```
var trip = (TripLogEntry)e.CurrentSelection.FirstOrDefault();
```

in this particular case, `CurrentSelection` is an `object` and yo want to cast it to the type `TripLogEntry`

Comment: "_those are parentheses_" [depends where you're from](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/168762/brackets-vs-parenthesis).

Answer (score 0):

You are casting *e.CurrentSelection.FirstOrDefault();* to TripLogEntry