# direction += (float)GD.RandRange(-Mathf.Pi / 4, Mathf.Pi / 4); c# what does the (float) mean here?

Tags: c#, godot

I am reading the Godot Engine documentation and saw something that makes no sense to me.

Can somebody explain what a **(float) or (Type)** in curved brackets means **before a class**?

```
direction += (float)GD.RandRange(-Mathf.Pi / 4, Mathf.Pi / 4);
mob.Rotation = direction;
```

OR

```
var mob = (Mob)MobScene.Instance();
```

This is the code snippet:

```
public void OnMobTimerTimeout()
{
    // Note: Normally it is best to use explicit types rather than the `var`
    // keyword. However, var is acceptable to use here because the types are
    // obviously Mob and PathFollow2D, since they appear later on the line.

    // Create a new instance of the Mob scene.
    var mob = (Mob)MobScene.Instance();

    // Choose a random location on Path2D.
    var mobSpawnLocation = GetNode<PathFollow2D>("MobPath/MobSpawnLocation");
    mobSpawnLocation.Offset = GD.Randi();

    // Set the mob's direction perpendicular to the path direction.
    float direction = mobSpawnLocation.Rotation + Mathf.Pi / 2;

    // Set the mob's position to a random location.
    mob.Position = mobSpawnLocation.Position;

    // Add some randomness to the direction.
    direction += (float)GD.RandRange(-Mathf.Pi / 4, Mathf.Pi / 4);
    mob.Rotation = direction;

    // Choose the velocity.
    var velocity = new Vector2((float)GD.RandRange(150.0, 250.0), 0);
    mob.LinearVelocity = velocity.Rotated(direction);

    // Spawn the mob by adding it to the Main scene.
    AddChild(mob);
}
```

It is from the article [The main game scene](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/getting_started/first_2d_game/05.the_main_game_scene.html) which is part of the official documentation of Godot.

I could not find some information about it.

Some **Source or examples that explains this** would be great, thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the meaning of brackets in this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64156845/what-is-the-meaning-of-brackets-in-this-code)

Comment: See [Explicit conversions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions#explicit-conversions) from C# documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a type cast. It's not about the class or its type, but about the return value of the function call. You don't give full context, but I assume the call to `GD.RandRange(-Mathf.Pi / 4, Mathf.Pi / 4);` returns a value of type `double` and the variable `direction` is of type `float`. Since there's no implicit conversion from `double` to `float` an explicit conversion is required. `(float)` does exactly that: It converts the return value of the `RandRange` method call to type `float`.